# Tableau Background color

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

This is really strange for me. i have 4 worksheets and in each worksheet i have set background color. I have put all the worksheets in Dashboard and set action that only when i select data from sheet1 Visualization others need to display the data else just blank data. This condition affects color as well. when no data is selected background color goes to white and it display the color only when i select some data in sheet1 visualization. I want to set permanent background color whether data is displaying or not. Let me know how to do this.

Thanks
Venkatesh

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/socialcopsdev/camelot

Comment: What version of Tableau? If all workbooks have the same bgcolor, you can set it as your dashboard background color.